# Replace string inside ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this `ng-include`

```
<ng-include
  ng-if="account.description"
  src="'templates/modals/document-upload/' + vm.currentAccount.description.toLowerCase() + '.html'"
></ng-include>
```

which works great.
I need to remove some spaces in the string of src (`vm.currentAccount.description.toLowerCase()`)

for that, I'm replacing by:
`vm.currentAccount.description.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')`

I'm getting a syntax error

> error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression at column 91 of the expression ['templates/modals/document-upload/' + vm.currentAccount.description.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').replace('&', '') + '.html'] starting at [/ /g, '') + '.html']

What am I missing? can't I call the replace with a regex there?

Comment: You really should be doing all that in your controller, not in your markup.

Comment: I know, sadly for some reason they want me to do here as the `toLowerCase()`. Thanks @isherwood I think in fact is duplicated, that would work